# how to upload sound file in asterisk?

Tags: asterisk

I have created a Asterisk server. I am able to place a call from one dialer to other dialer and its working properly. When connection established between both dialers, I need a voice script to be played, provided by asterisk.

I need to upload my own voice script(sound file) in asterisk server. I want to use java as my back end. So is there any java api(or any web service URL that can be accessed from outside application) that I can upload my sound file to `/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/en` directly.

I am trying to play that file using fastagi api of asterisk-java. can anyone help me for how to achieve that?

Comment: Asterisk is a bit crazy to get running, so upvote

Comment: you got the solution, in my case i have admin panel from where user can upload the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the file in the `/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/en` path, and refer to the file name, without the extension in your dial plan, in your extensions.conf

```
exten => s,1,Answer()
exten => s,n,Read(dtmfvalue,agent-newlocation,3)
```

Here `agent-newlocation.gsm` is in the folder `/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/en`

Comment: how to upload sound file at position /var/lib/asterisk/sounds/en ? I also upload file from admin panel of asterisk server but it is placed at sound/custom something path.

Comment: Use scp. Just like ssh, you can use scp to upload download files to from your remote server.

Comment: Is there any other way to upload from local machine using java code or other asterisk admin panel?

Answer (score 1):

You can check on [voip-info.org](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Dial) about Dial command.
Add A(filename) option so that option.gsm file will be played to called party

> A(x): Play an announcement (x.gsm) to the called party.

Like:

```
Dial(SIP/1111,30,A(announce))
```

When you make a dial.
As @Siddharth said, you need to have announce.gsm (or .alaw, .wav) file in `/var/lib/asterisk/sounds/en` folder.

If you are using GUI tools like FreePBX, AsteriskNOW, than you probably can upload sound file in GUI and add option on extension you want (in this case 1111) to play that exact prompt that you uploaded and named before.

Comment: thanks @mirkobrankovic, your answered helped me figure out my next step. thought I got stuck and a exception (please check my latest question on asterisk).

Comment: If that's the answer you were looking for, check/accept answer under the vote up/down, so that other know it's good resolution, thanks, glad I was able to help :)